# Cython: How to import global variables from a module?

Tags: python, c++, c, import, cython

A module with global C variable:

```
# mymod.pyx (compiled to mymod.so)
cdef int myvar
```

**How to access `myvar` from another file?**
Scenario 1:

```
# myapp.pyx (import module only)
import mymod
print(mymod.myvar) # myvar is Python object, not int
```

Scenario 2:

```
# myapp.pyx (import variable directly)
from mymod import myvar # Error, no such myvar as Python var
```

Scenario 3:

```
# myapp.pyx (import with cimport, needs .pxd file)
from mymod cimport myvar
```

I wish to use **.pyx files only, if possible**. Unless there are no choices, I may use .pxd files, how to move `myvar` to .pxd file in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that `cdef` globals in a module must be in `.pxd` files.

For example:

```
# submod.pyx
some code...
```

```
# submod.pxd
cdef int myvar
```

```
# mod.pyx
cimport submod
print(submod.myvar)
```

```
# app.py
import mod
```

Comment: Do you know if the cython function can access globals defined in python? E.g. in a .py file do `global GLOBAL_VAR; GLOBAL_VAR = 1` and then try to access it in a .pyx file.

Comment: Import that py file normally, in pyx file, use regular 'import' key word